# How to remove letters from a Property?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installscript

I'm creating a Basic MSI, and i'm using System Search to read a value from the registry, and store it in a Property. I would like to use this property in a cfile path, but unfortunately the value, what I read from the registry looks like this: `\\MyServer.MyDomain.com`. Does anyone know ho could I remove, the two "\" ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to wrote a custom action.  The InstallScript function [StrReplace](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield14langref/StrReplace.htm) will likely be useful.